# How to send keyboard input(strokes) to background process in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, process, terminal

I have started a python script in terminal (this terminal has been closed) and sent it to background. Now this program expects some input from the keyboard and keeps waiting. How do I send input,  'y\n'(letter 'y' followed by a Enter) to this program? Assume its pid is 1234.

I have tested this method but it does not work.

`echo 'y\n' | /proc/1234/fd/0` and `echo 'y\n' > /proc/1234/fd/0`

Update:
The relevant part of my python script is :

```
ans = raw_input('Overwrite?(y/n):')
if ans == 'y':
    do_something()
else:
    do_otherthing()
```

Comment: What python program? What library is used to read? Is it reading from `/dev/tty` or from `/dev/stdin` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is a python script I wrote. It dose not read any lib. It is reading from /dev/stdin.

Comment: Then you should show the relevant parts of the script in your question... So please **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have improved the question.

Comment: Simplest way: improve your script to handle program options and have a "batch" mode which does not call `rawinput`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo -ne 'y\n' > /proc/1234/fd/0
```

An alternative could be to use the command `yes`. For more information use `man yes`.

```
yes > /proc/1234/fd/0
```

Comment: Does it help if it's `echo -e` so the `\n` will be interpreted as a new line instead of a literal `\n` sequence?

Comment: @EricRenouf Still not working. Thanks! In fact, I wonder if it is possible.

Comment: @ShuaiZhang Look at this example with the use of program cat. http://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi/178470

Comment: I'm trying to signal the KB signal to running GUI application from the command line, eg getting  `Audacity` start recording by sending the keyboard letter `R` but it didn't work to me .